# How can fixed-point combinators make recursive constructs terminate?

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion, compiler-construction, combinators

[Fixed-point combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) provide a way for anonymous functions to refer to themselves or to build mutually recursive structures. Although useful in lambda-calculus, they are essentially superfluous in modern programming languages because most if not all support recursion, lambdas and closures.

Also, fixed-point combinators can make recursive constructs like left-recursive grammar parsers terminate. Consider [Lickman 1995](https://sites.google.com/a/lickman.com/paul-lickman/), who proves termination for his implementation but never actually mentions *how* it works (it's just a step-by-step derivation from lattice theory to the haskell implementation) and *why* he needs fixed-point combinators in a language that already supports recursion natively.

How does it work and why does he require a fixed-point combinator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a quick scan, at the end of 5.3, Lickman writes "As defined above, fixS is ensured to been sufficiently productive on all continuous inputs."

The point is to get the fixpoint operator to produce enough output so that parsing can continue. You can't do that for a general `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` but specializing `a` to `Set a`, or later `Parser a`, gives enough structure (namely that of a lattice) to work with.

Again, I've just looked through the thesis cursorily, but I think the proof (in section 5.5) of the statement "`h :: Parser a -> Parser a` maintains the property of productivity ==> `fixP h` is productive" is key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's something I don't understand regarding your statement about the output of the fixpoint operator, though: as I understand it's a single value `x` such that `f(x) = x` for some function `f`, how is that _enough_ or _not enough_ for parsing to continue?

Comment: Very good question! Consider for a simplified example the function `f = (1 :) :: [Int] -> [Int]`. The least fixed point of `f` is an infinite lists of ones, and as such can not be computed *in its entirety*. But you don't need the whole list to be able to compute `take 5 (fix f)`!  What complicates matters in the thesis is that `Parser` (and `Set`, to a lesser extent) aren't as simple as `[Int]` so laziness doesn't help automagically. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I think it does: `fixP` gets me the parser that produces the biggest set of unique parse trees so that `h(p) = p` holds, where `h` is `fixP`'s first argument and `p` my parser. So `h` is just used to "check" that a given parser is actually equivalent to the original, unproductive parser?

Answer (score 3):

Sure thing. Here is a simple right-recursive grammar in three rules:

```
S -> b T
T -> a S
T -> a
```

These three rules let us build a parser for recognizing these strings:

```
type Parser = String -> (Bool, String)
s :: Parser
s "" = (False, "")
s (c : cs) = if c == 'b' then t cs else (False, cs)

t :: Parser
t "" = (False, "")
t (c : cs) 
  | c == 'a' && cs == "" = (True, "") 
  | c /= 'a' = (False, cs)
  | otherwise = s cs
```

If you want to do more general parsing, just specialize the `Bool` to instead have some data structure, perhaps stored in a `Maybe` to indicate failure. Returning `(False, ___)` on a failed parse would help if S had some other rules too, like e.g. `S -> T T` and `T -> b b`. Then when we get a 'b' followed by (False, ___) we rewind to try `S -> T T`. These sorts of grammars can be done with a bit of elbow-grease and recursion.

The three rules above will successfully match strings like "ba", "baba", and so on. We could also write these strings left-recursively as:

```
S -> T a
T -> S b
T -> b
```

What happens if you try to write the same parsers above? An infinite loop, if you're looking at the front of the string. The problem is that the function S will call the function T first thing, and then T will call S first thing, and they will mutually recurse ad infinitum. The computer's not smart enough to know that the postconditions ("followed by an a", "followed by a b") make further solution impossible; it just descends into your functions and trusts that you know what you're doing.

How does a good fixed-point combinator help? Well, think of these rules as describing a tree: then function evaluation traverses that tree depth-first, and this particular tree is infinite in that direction.  A breadth-first traversal, on the other hand, can be based on these rules and can pick up the result which uses the fewest of these functions possible, and that is the 'least fixed point' for a certain function based on this grammar. So that's why the *right* fixed-point combinator (based either on the `diag` in the paper or the lattice-theory combinator) can terminate when describing these rules, while naive recursion will not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does make a lot of sense. Yet, if the combinator only changes the traversal strategy from depth-first to breadth-first then why would the author not be explicit about it? Breadth-first was already used in '83.

Comment: Well he actually rejects `diag` (which I think does do an explicit BFS) for a better combinator based on lattice theory, so that's why there's more math. The idea of fixed points is captured by `fix f = let a = f a in a`, `fix :: (x -> x) -> x`. Call this a fixer on `x`. You can use this e.g. on `fix (const 0)` or `fix (1:)` or `fix (\f n -> if n < 10 then n : f (n + 1) else []) 3`. His idea is that we can do better fixed points for `A -> [B]` since `[B]` is a "lattice", so we get better fixers on `s -> [(a, s)]`. (Is his approach the same as the MonadFix instance for []? I don't know.)